# passing Object into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

```js
var initGrid = function() {

  //creating a grid while initialising it
  var grid = [];

  // declaring each grid element as a Object having three properties
  var gridElement = {
    x: Number,
    y: Number,
    val: Number
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      gridElement.x = i;
      gridElement.y = j;
      gridElement.val = 0;
      grid.push(gridElement);
    };
  };

  return grid;
};

console.log(initGrid());
```

when i run this code on console, all Objects of grid Array are having  same values for x and y which are 9 and 9....

But i want to create objects having different values acc to loop variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, Object are passed by reference. You will have to create different object in every iteration.

Following is the sample.

```js
var initGrid = function() {

  //creating a grid while initialising it
  var grid = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      var gridElement = {}
      gridElement.x = i;
      gridElement.y = j;
      gridElement.val = 0;
      grid.push(gridElement);
    };
  };

  return grid;
};

console.log(initGrid());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not declaring a gridElement type that way; Javascript doesn't do that, Typescript would (but that's beside the point).

You see the same values because you only ever have one gridElement object, the one you created with

```
var gridElement = {
  x: Number,
  y: Number,
  val: Number
};
```

which, for context, initializes an object with properties `x`, `y`, and `val` all pointing to the `Number` constructor function.

Every loop iteration is mutating this same object, and pushing a reference to that one object onto your grid, so you don't actually have 100 grid elements with `x` and `y` equal to `9` - you have 100 references to the same object, where the last values you wrote to `x` and `y` were both `9`.

As an example, you can create new objects per loop as follows:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    var newGridElement = {
      x: i,
      y: j,
      val: 0
    };
    grid.push(newGridElement);
    console.log(newGridElement);
  };
};
```

You can declare a `GridElement` constructor function and type of your own, but if you really need that, you'll be doing something like [defining a Javascript class](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/) of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a user-defined object, with a function and an instance with `new` operator [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)]. This gives an interface for the data structure.

```js
var initGrid = function () {
    var grid = [];

    function GridElement(x, y, val) {            // user-defined function
        this.x = x;                              // properties
        this.y = y;
        this.val = val;
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            grid.push(new GridElement(i, j, 0)); // use an instance of GridElement with new
        };
    };

    return grid;
};

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(initGrid(), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```